# What does "floog" mean?

Tags: terminology

There are two sentences in *[Badass: Making Users Awesome](https://books.google.com.tw/books?id=fuFwBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA263&lpg=PA263&dq=floog%20cover&source=bl&ots=9ZO0mXm6Sf&sig=EITPdls2lLggI-5S240pCM7oK1M&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=floog%20cover&f=false)*:

> Always close the **floog cover** before replacing the Y widget.
>
> Well, because the Y widget interferes with the **floog's op connector**.

What does the **floog** mean? what is **floog's op connector**?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is an example dialog between a technical support person and a (very dim) user. It is intended to demonstrate how to provide good technical support. The dialog is made-up, and the word **floog** is very made-up.

**floog** is an example of a [placeholder name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placeholder_name):

> Placeholder names are words that can refer to objects or people whose names are temporarily forgotten, **irrelevant**, or unknown in the context in which they are being discussed.

I suspect that **op** is also a placeholder name. Alternatively, given that it qualifies **connector**, it may be  meant to sound a little like an abbreviation for **output**. Either way, its meaning is not relevant to the principles that the dialog is intended to demonstrate.

Comment: The term that came to my mind was *metasyntactic variable*, which is basically a nonsense placeholder word that can be used to take on any role in a syntax as necessary.

Comment: @stangdon, I considered that, but the *variable* in *metasyntactic variable* suggests that it's a computer science term. This wiki article is of the same opinion: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metasyntactic_variable

Comment: @JavaLatte Thanks for your careful explanation & answer. But what does "op" mean in that context? I guess it's over power.

Comment: @Jodoo, you are welcome. Sorry, I did no see the **op** part of your question: I have updated my answer to explain it.

Comment: @JavaLatte Never mind, it's my fault. You are so awesome! :-)